# Align label text and input checkbox beside each other

Tags: html, css

I have the code below, however, it is showing up like this in the browser:

```
       checkbox
             yes, I give permission
```

How do I fix this? Is this the natural way, where it will never be aligned, and I need to style it differently; or is there a different way in general to do it? I'm not sure what to do!

```css
label {
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    color:#000; 
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:900;
    display: inline-block;
    /* width: 140px; */
    text-align: right;
}

input {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<label for="permission"><input type="checkbox" id="permission" name="permission" value="Yes">Yes, I give permission </label>
```

Comment: Make both inline-block

Comment: How do you want it to look?

Comment: @j08691 to line up beside each other perfectly in a row. like `checkbox yes, I give permission` instead of being below

Comment: Just get rid of `display: block;` and `width: 300px;`

Answer (score 1):

**Here you go...**

```css
#for_label {
  padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 900;
  display: inline-block;
  /* width: 140px; */
  text-align: right;
}

#for_input {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <label id='for_label' for="permission"><input id='for_input' type="checkbox" id="permission" name="permission" value="Yes">Yes, I give permission</label>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this looks good, but my only problem now is the fact that there is a huge space in between the checkbox and text. do you know how to fix that?

Comment: maybe it is just a problem with my code then, because it is now going below the box again. strange :(

Comment: I updated my answer. Try to copy paste HTML and CSS exactly like I written. I linked the CSS style with your HTML via id. What about now?

Comment: same thing. I appreciate the help. It myst be something in my css files that are screwing it up. I will continue to investigate.

Comment: Edit your question and post a little bit more of your code. I'll try to help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232593/discussion-between-gianluca-and-r-b).

Answer (score 1):

You have used a `width` on the input which is making the text to go to the next line. Have removed the same and added `inline-block` to keep the text next to the checkbox.

```css
label {
    padding: 12px 12px 12px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    color:#000; 
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:900;
    display: inline-block;
    /* width: 140px; */
    text-align: right;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 5px;
    display: inlin-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<label for="permission"><input type="checkbox" id="permission" name="permission" value="Yes">Yes, I give permission </label>
```